# Android tutorial teleop problems

Tags: ros, android-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I am having problems with "android_tutorial_teleop". It compiles ok, but the app crashes when touching the virtualJoysticView.
The problem is that "currentVelocityCommand" is null when setting velocities.
I have tried:

```
currentVelocityCommand =publisher.newMessage();
```

as the Issue 109 of rosjava says (http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=android&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=109)
but it doesn't work...

Please, could anybody help me??

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44427/android-tutorial-teleop-problems/) by [JMata](https://answers.ros.org/users/2907/jmata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2012-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

finally it works! i tried:

```
currentVelocityCommand = publisher.newMessage();
```

after publisher initialization.
It is necessary to have the master running, the publisher needs to be initialized ok, if not, currentVelocityCommand = publisher.newMessage(); won't work.

---

Originally posted by [JMata](https://answers.ros.org/users/2907/jmata/) with karma: 30 on 2012-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1